# Can SQL Server 2008 R2 get email name resolution from Office 365?

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

We just moved from an on premise Exchange server to Office 365's Exchange Online.  My question is, is there any way to still get email name resolution from Office 365?  I have many stored procedures and SQL Agent jobs where the name is specified instead of the email address, and I'd like to know if I can do something to avoid needing to find and change all of them.

So, can "John Doe" be translated to "jdoe@domain.com" using Sql Server 2008 R2 db_mail and Office 365 Exchange Online, like I could do with the old on premise Exchange?

Comment: Does this article meet your needs? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2013/02/25/how-to-configure-sql-database-mail-to-send-emails-using-office-365-exchange-online-a-walkthrough/

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone -Not really, I was able to use it as an SMTP server just fine, the question was regarding name resolution.  My answer below is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be "no, you can't".  Thanksfully our email addresses were consistant, so I was able to write a function that transforms the [firstname lastname] or [groupname] into the valid email  address.  For anyone outside our company, their raw email address can be supplied.